# Choose option then get value Python Scraper

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have this python **scraper** that I followed a tutorial and had help on here to create. Is it possible to select the buttons on this website (ex 10g) and get the price (even if it is just for one of the options)? https://deltaalternatives.com/product/bulk-delta-8-hemp-distillate-9pound-hammer/

The price for each option doesn't show until they are pressed.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://deltaalternatives.com/product/bulk-delta-8-hemp-distillate-9pound-hammer/"

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:92.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/92.0"
}

page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

price = soup.select_one(".price bds").text
print(price)
```

Answer (score 0):

That data is stored within one of the attributes of a form element. You can extract that and handle with json library. Some items within the json returned have values which are html which would need re-parsing with html parser. Example for size with prices:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import json

r = requests.get('https://deltaalternatives.com/product/bulk-delta-8-hemp-distillate-9pound-hammer/')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
data = json.loads(soup.select_one('.variations_form')['data-product_variations'])

for i in data:
    print('size:', i['attributes']['attribute_pa_size'])
    print('display regular price:', i['display_regular_price'])
    print('display price:', i['display_price'])
    print('formatted values with currency symbol', bs(i['price_html']).get_text())
    print()
```